# Is there way for Swift code to detect if it's being run in a playground or not?

Tags: swift, xcode7

To be able to test GameKit features, I'd like to be able to detect if the code is being run in a Playground, so that it can just skip the network calls. Is there a way to do this?

**edit:**

Forget about GameKit--that just muddies the issue. There are many different scenarios where this would be useful. It's really just a simple question about whether a specific function call exists or not: is there a method that returns `true` if the code is running in a Playground?

Comment: Code should't depend on where it runs, it should just do its task. Maybe the user of your code should be able to set this himself whether networking is done or not.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're getting at with the axiom, but it's a little misstated. All code is context-dependent. Literally every line of code depends on where it runs. I believe you're addressing separation of concerns. That is to say, the choice to make network calls should be separate from the code making those calls. Which is right and fine and good. And my actual question is "can Swift code detect if it's being run in a playground?"

Comment: Thanks! If you want to make that an answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a documented way to do it, but there are some undocumented things you can do.

Here's a technique that works in both Xcode 7 with Swift 2.2 and Xcode 8 with Swift 3.0, in both macOS and iOS playgrounds: check for a bundle whose identifier starts with `"com.apple.dt"`.

```
// Swift 2.2

if NSBundle.allBundles().contains({ ($0.bundleIdentifier ?? "").hasPrefix("com.apple.dt.") }) {
    print("in playground")
} else {
    print("not in playground")
}
```

```
// Swift 3.0

if Bundle.allBundles.contains(where: { ($0.bundleIdentifier ?? "").hasPrefix("com.apple.dt.") }) {
    print("in playground")
} else {
    print("not in playground")
}
```

Note that `com.apple.dt.` is not a prefix reserved specifically for a playground-related bundle; the `dt` part standards for something like “developer tool”. So there might be circumstances where you get a false positive: there's a bundle that matches but you're not in a playground. I'm not aware of any such circumstances, but there might be some. I did test an `IBDesignable` view in a macOS xib under Xcode 7, and it didn't have any `com.apple.dt.` bundles loaded.

Comment: Doesn’t work in Swift Playgrounds, iOS 16.1

Answer (score 0):

I updated the previous answer using the application’s bundle ID which contains “swift-playgrounds”:

```swift
public var inPlayground: Bool {
    if Bundle.allBundles.contains(where: { ($0.bundleIdentifier ?? "").contains("swift-playgrounds") }) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```